# Mocking angularjs $filter with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I want to test a controller that has a $filter like below

```
$filter('number')(someNumber, 0).replaceAll(',', ":")
```

I can mock the filter like below

```
mocknumberFilter = jasmine.createSpy();
filter = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(mocknumberFilter);
```

but having difficulties with .replaceAll.. getting the following error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceAll' of undefined

thanks

Answer (score 1):

ok I got another way around..instead of using createspy..i did this

```
var mockFilter = function() {
                var ob = {replaceAll:function(){return true;}}
                return ob;
            };

            beforeEach(function() {
                module(function($provide) {
                    $provide.value('numberFilter', mockFilter );
                });
            });
```